Is this kick from the Legend of Korra actually possible, balance-wise?
See below. It isn't really a kick because I believe your leg is extended only as a counterweight, but I didn't know what else to call it. My intuition says that possibly your torso would be too top-heavy for this to work. Anyone have any ideas?


I'll just say that I've seen similar things in various Chinese kung-fu styles. For example 8 Drunken Immortals. The shaolin monks practice a drunken style as well which has very similar movements. Taoist straight sword styles have something similar also.
There are two ways to interpret this still frame image. First is that it's actually a snapshot of continuous motion, and we can't see what happens next. Second is that it's a stationary pose held indefinitely.
In the first case, this is part of continuous motion. You will fall backwards as you do this technique, landing on your back while doing a breakfall. It's also possible to coil your body as you're doing this (like in spear and straight sword forms), and then pushing off the leg to dive towards your opponent, landing on your belly or even landing in a squat position on your feet.
If this is interpreted as a stationary pose that is to be held, instead, you can't achieve it by keeping your entire body past the center of balance like the picture shows. That's obvious. You'll fall backwards if you do. Instead, you have to tilt your base leg on an angle instead of keeping it straight up and down. That will move your torso ahead of the balance point. In doing so, you'll need to make an arch with your back. You will not be able to have your back perfectly horizontal with the floor. It will be arched. So it will end up looking similar but not exactly the same as this picture.
There is a third option. That extended leg and foot can be pressed up against something or hooking something in the environment to prevent falling.
My bet is on the second interpretation. The artist exaggerated or didn't understand this pose well enough when drawing it.
That's about all I can offer. You can check out YouTube to see if you can spot it or something like it. But I wouldn't know a name for the technique off of the top of my head. It probably varies based on the style.
Hope that helps.

Bending forward, one yoga site classifies this as an intermediate level static yoga pose, the standing stick pose. Bending in this direction, the body is not too top-heavy to balance. If you had fabulous back flexibility, I imagine you could also basically do this backwards.

I'd add as a mild caveat here that the human foot points forward with only a small outreach of heel, which does make a fairly significant different in the ability to pitch weight forwards and backwards without significant shifting of the hips. :)
